# once map api is called on my page, and users continue to use the map function, am I charged every click someone searches on the map?

Tags: java

I have pulled in the map api in my site. However, I see that it comes with the entire map and its a clickable searchable map. The more customers use the app, and I charged more ?

just the standard address lookup address like on other sites. I did not want a searchable map.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.